# How to avoid selecting first value in single select list of values type mandatory input control in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm using JasperReports 6.0.1. i am creating a report where one input control is single select list of values which is mandatory and i am giving three name and value pairs.

here is my parameter

```
<parameter name="daily_weekly_monthly" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

when i run my report by default first name is being selected i don't want to do that i want user to select from the drop down when he runs report. how can i achieve it? i guess there might be an attribute to put in jrxml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Report unit to 'Always Prompt' for input controls.

From Repository Explorer, select your report and select 'Edit'. From here, click on the 'Controls & Resource'. Here you will see Input Control Options, where there is a checkbox named 'Always Prompt'. Check this to enable prompting all the time.